# AngularJS and Karma, Cannot call method 'module' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I start **karma** inside an AngularJs **yeoman** scaffolding.
The error "Cannot call method 'module' of undefined" is in gruntfile.js, generated by yeoman, on the first line `module.exports = function (grunt) { ...`

The karma.conf.js is

```
module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({

// base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
basePath: '',

frameworks: ['jasmine'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
    '**/*.js',
    'app/bower_components/**/*.js'
],

exclude: [ ],

reporters: ['progress'],

// web server port
port: 9876,

colors: true,

logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

autoWatch: true,

browsers: ['Chrome'],

captureTimeout: 60000,

singleRun: false
});
};
```

angular.js is incluse inside bower_components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `files` declaration. Because you load `**/*.js` your subsequent inclusion of the bower components is unnecessary (it's already been loaded by the first call).

Karma doesn't try to be clever, so you need to specify which things you want loading first. As an example, from one of my `karma.conf.js` files:

```
files: [
    // Required libraries
    'assets/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
    'assets/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
    'assets/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
    'assets/bower_components/ng-table/ng-table.js',

    // App under test
    'assets/javascripts/**/!(*.spec).js',

    // Mocks
    'test/js/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js',

    // Templates
    'assets/javascripts/angular/**/*.html',

    // Finally... tests
    'assets/javascripts/**/*.spec.js',
    'test/js/unit**/*.js'
],
```

In the above, I'm explicitly loading the required libraries first. I then load all non-test JS, before the Angular mocking library. Then I load templates, and finally bring in the tests.

You can use the `!(*.spec).js` notation to omit spec files (alter to match you naming convention of course) from the first load.

Comment: Glad this solved your problem. I always appreciate the upvote too :)

Answer (score 1):

this line `app/bower_components/**/*.js` does not work properly, and you don't want to use that, because there can be multiple `.js` files in the same folder (for example regular and minified) and you don't want to include all of them

just change that line to all of the angular files manually and it should work

```
app/bower_components/angular/angular.js,
app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js
```

and don't forget to include `angular-mocks`, there are definitions of global variables accessible in specs - `module`, `inject` ...